# Why td size gets so wide in my bootstrap table?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table with some elements in it:

```
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <h5>Orders from Restaurant</h5>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="pr-0">
                                <img src="../../../storage/images/food/sharshara/appetizer_wing_preview.jpg"
                                    height="100px" class="img-thumbnail">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h4 class="">Chicken wings</h4>
                                <p>No sauce, extra dust</p>
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 100px">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" id="button-addon1">
                                                <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="1"
                                            aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                                        <div class="input-group-append">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="button-addon1">
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

But for some reason my table column gets wide, i tried to change width both in css and td parameter, nothing helps.
[image]

Comment: That's how tables work... you have less control of column width. What are you trying to? Minimize the width of the column to fit the image?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to fit column width to image size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to "fix"..

- use width:1% to shrink the column width to fit the image
- don't use `img-thumbnail` because that will shrink the image

HTML

```
   <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="pr-0" style="width:1%">
                <img src="..." />
            </td>
            <td>
                ..
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/epJgrepmYB